# ASP.NET Send variable in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
**ASPX CODE** this is the aspx code
<% for (int i = 0; i < pricePageObj.cartItemsgetset; i++)
                { %>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1 ">
                    <% Response.Write(i + 1); %>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 ">
                    <% Response.Write(svcID[i]); %>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 ">
                    <% Response.Write(svcName[i]); %>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 ">
                    <% Response.Write(svcDesc[i]); %>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 ">
                    <% Response.Write(svcCharges[i]); %>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 ">
                    <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-danger" runat="server" Text="Remove"  CommandArgument="dont know how to pass i here" OnCommand="onRemove" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <%} %>
```

Let's say i=0 ; i<5; i++. so for loop will go for 5 times. so i want to send `i` as a parameter in the code behind to read the value of i.
**C# CODE** code behind

```
public void onRemove(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string indexx = Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("String index = " + indexx);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }


    }
```

I want to send that 'i' index in the code behind. Any help?
When i clicked on the button, i want to read that `i` in the `onRemove` event.
any help?

Comment: you mean send it from code behind?

Comment: No i want to send that in the code behind. i want to get that index in the c# function onRemove.

Comment: do you want to pass svcCharges[i] or just the 'i' to the code behind?

Comment: @AmrElgarhy Just the 'i'.

Comment: Could you show `onRemove` event?

Comment: I am doing nothing in the `onRemove` event. But here you go. I want to catch that index in the event `onRemove`.
When i clicked on it, it sends that address in the event. I have tried through commandArgument but it's not working.

Comment: `public void onRemove(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            
            try
            {
                string indexx = Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("String index = " + indexx);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }


        }`

Comment: i want to get that index on button click.
it doesn't matter if it came through comandArgument or some other way.

Comment: Normally, you could assign value to `CommandArgument`. How do you assign that value? Please tell us what you are trying to achieve over all instead of what is not working.

Comment: @Win ya i know we can assign a value to `CommandArgument` like `CommandArgument="some value"` but how can i pass a variable? or how can i assign a variable to `CommandArgument` ?

Comment: `how can i pass a variable` Where do you want to pass the variable from?

Comment: seams he want to read the 'i' variable from the code behind, at least this what I understood so far.

Comment: @AmrElgarhy Yes i want to read `i` from the code behind in `onRemove` event on the click of button.
when the button clicks. it send the value to `onRemove`.
this is what i want.

Comment: Could you show the rest of the code both ASPX and code behind?

Comment: @win i updated the code for you.

Comment: Ideally, you should use ***ListView server control***. What are pricePageObj.cartItemsgetset, svcID, svcName, svcDesc and svcCharges?

Comment: pricePageObj.cartItemsgetset is `int`
svcID, svcName, svcDesc and svcCharges are `List<>`

Comment: You might want to look into a `Repeater` or `GridView` Control. That's much easier that writing a loop on the aspx page.

Comment: You don't want to pass the *variable*, but it's *value*. So  as Win said, set `CommandArgument="<%= i %>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how we normally display a collection inside ***Bootstrap divs*** in ASP.NET Web Form. If we want to manipulate individual row, we use ***ItemDataBound*** event.

It seems a lot of code compare to your original question, but this is a recommended approach in ASP.NET Web Form.

[image]

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView1" 
    ItemPlaceholderID="ItemPlaceholder"
    OnItemDataBound="ListView_ItemDataBound">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="ItemPlaceholder"></asp:Panel>
        <asp:DataPager runat="server" ID="DataPager" PageSize="3">
            <Fields>
                <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonCount="5" PreviousPageText="<" NextPageText=">" />
            </Fields>
        </asp:DataPager>
    </LayoutTemplate>        
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <%# Eval("Id") %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <%# Eval("Name") %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-danger" runat="server" Text="Remove" 
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' ID="RemoveButton" 
                    OnCommand="RemoveButton_Command" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

### Code Behind

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public partial class About : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ListView1.DataSource = new List<User>
            {
                new User {Id = 1, Name = "John"},
                new User {Id = 2, Name = "Marry"},
                new User {Id = 3, Name = "Nancy"},
                new User {Id = 4, Name = "Eric"},
            };
            ListView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void RemoveButton_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

    }

    protected void ListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            User user = e.Item.DataItem as User;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<% Response.Write(i + 1); %>
```

By doing this, you are passing `i` to the Response.Write method.

You should be able to just write a method in your code behind.

Code behind sample method:

```
protected int Foo(int bar){
    //do something with bar

    return bar;
}
```

You should be able to do this on the .aspx page now:

`<% Response.Write(Foo(1) + 1); %>`

You can access all of the methods in your code behind by putting the below line at the top of your page, replacing MyCoolPage with your page name.  This line should be added for you automagically, though, when you create a web form page:

`<%@ Page CodeBehind="MyCoolPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyCoolPage" Language="C#" %>`

Instead of doing what you are doing with your button, just add an OnClick event instead of what you are doing now, as follows:

`<asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-danger" runat="server" Text="Remove"  OnClick="DoSomethingCool(i) />`

DoSomethingCool:

```
protected void DoSomethingCool(int index){
    try
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("index = " + 
         index);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.